# Locally lipschitz $f$ implies solutions for $x' = f(x(t))$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given locally Lipschitz $f$, I had the problem to show all solutions of $$x'(t) = f(x(t))$$ are either constant or strictly monotonous. If $x'$ has no zeros then the statement is obvious.

However, in the case where $x'$ has a zero at $t_0$, i.e., $f(x(t_0))=0$, the solution manual states that the constant function $c(t) = x(t_0)$ solves the initial value problem 
$$y'(t) = f(y(t))\quad\forall t\in \mathbb{R},\\ y(t_0) = x(t_0)$$
on all of $\mathbb{R}$. It doesn't say why we can just take the maximum interval of existence to be $\mathbb{R}$, and as far as I understand Picard, we only know there is some (possibly small) interval of existence $[t_0-\epsilon, t_0+\epsilon]$ for our solution!

Where is the error in my thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant function $x:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n$, $x(t)=x_0$, is a solution, as it satisfies the ODE in every point. Nothing more is needed.

You can take any differentiable function and test it on the ODE, if it is satisfied in every point of the domain of the function, this function is a solution.

Picard-Lindelöf (and also the Peano theorem) just tells you that some solution (non-trivial, with open domain) exists, it in no way prevents any superior (in the sense of inclusion of domains and function restriction) solution to exist.